# How get the thumbnail from YouTube

Tags: java, android, youtube

Thumbnail from the video in YouTube.

I want to add the ability to add images from video which I get in my method *useLinkInput*.

Now I have a dialog, where I have the following code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String string = input.getText().toString();
    useLinkInput(string);
}
```

And method *useLinkInput*:

```
private void useLinkInput(String input) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(input);
    String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
    url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID +"/0.jpg";
    Log.d("url", url);
}
```

When the user pastes the link in the dialog and presses OK, I get this in the log image:

```
D/url: http://img.youtube.com/vi/null/0.jpg
```

But it is null* (it didn’t show the image).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/

Comment: @Max i don't want to use Youtube Api, have i any way?

Comment: Why would you not want to use it? It is specifically built to do things exactly like this.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey is to hard for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example, your YouTube video URL is as below.

```
String youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxo0Upfz48Q";
```

In this URL parameter, `v=Rxo0Upfz48Q` stands for the video ID. So, in the above URL videoID is `Rxo0Upfz48Q`.

You can get videoID using the below code.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(youtubeUrl);
String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
```

Now using videoID you can make the URL to get the first frame of that YouTube video like below.

```
String url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/0.jpg";
```

Now you can get a thumbnail image from the above URL and display in your imageview.

Comment: But if i need to get every time random url?

Comment: As I have described in answer you can make random thumbnail url using VideoID. And you can parse VideoID by `uri.getQueryParameter("v")` from your youtube url. Check my updated answer.

Comment: can u invite me in chat please? i want to show u my code, if u have time

Comment: Ya sure. I don't know how to invite in chat. can you initiate?

Comment: Same problem) i will update a little bit question, one moment please.

Comment: i need to use split in link? or..? because image didn t display

Comment: what is your link in dialog ? check log of input string ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124802/discussion-between-vadim-morozov-and-priyank-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Use **HTTPS://** it will work properly.

```
String videoThumb = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId +"/0.jpg";
```